# How can I extract links using R from a webpage that is javascript enabled

Tags: javascript, html, r, hyperlink, rvest

I am trying to extract all the links on a webpage: "https://coronavirus.data.gov.uk/archive/"

For other webpages, I have used the following approach with the rvest pacakge, that has worked well:

```
url_page<-"https://coronavirus.data.gov.uk/archive/"
webpage<-read_html(url_page)
all_links<-html_attr(html_nodes(webpage, "a"), "href")
```

However this produces a null value for this webpage. For example, it works well for "https://www.gov.uk/guidance/coronavirus-covid-19-information-for-the-public"

I think it might have something to do with the webpage being javascript enabled. Does anyone know how to extract the links for a webpage like this using R?

Answer (score 0):

I believe you are using rvest package.

```
url = read_html("https://coronavirus.data.gov.uk/archive/")
url %>%
  html_nodes('.govuk-template__body') %>%
  html_text()
```

Returns error message on running javascript.
You might  use `RSelenium` package as solution which enables to scrape data with browser use to load the table first.